# Search by regular pattern in iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, regex, nsregularexpression

Trying to search bbcode-style tags with regular expression:

For example, I needed `[user=1]John Dow[/user]` with regular: `[[user=[0-9]+].*?[/user]]` 
But couldn't receive needed result.

Comment: Escape the opening square brackets `\[user=[0-9]+].*?\[/user]`

Comment: Would you like to use `[` as special for making character ranges or look for it explicitly? Both? How about escaping it in cases for literal "search for a ["?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the outer pair of brackets and escape the literal brackets (unlike the *range-of-characters* brackets)

```
let pattern = "\\[user=[0-9]+\\].*?\\[/user\\]"
```